# Pass variables in url using POST

Tags: php

Assuming I have a two pages (page1 and page2), there are variable values I want to send to page2 without using `$_GET` function but instead `$_POST` through a url.
Example on page1

```
<?php 
   $name="Dman";
   $id="12";
   $level="122";
?>
 <a href="page2.php">Goto Page2</a>
```

On page 2, I want to receive the variable values using POST.

```
name:dman
id:  12
level:122
```

**UPDATE**

Please what I am trying to achieve, is to prevent showing items being transmitted from one page to the another, when url is been used. I read some blogs and they are like, using POST workaround can help achieve this.On the contrary if there is a way to avoid using `"?id=$id&name=$name"` on a url but still receive your variables on the next page, I would be grateful to know.
Thanks for helping

Comment: *"but instead $_POST through a url"* - Can't be done.

Comment: If you want to use urls, uses $_GET. You can also uses your session $_SESSION if the situation permits it

Comment: Nope! You can't use `$_POST` with query strings

Comment: what is the difference?! why would you need to use $_POST to access querystring?! i mean if you realllly want to do it, then at the start of your PHP script do `$_POST = $_GET` .. but I really wouldn't recommend it!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the GET method if you want to pass parameters in the URL. POST is a different method and it's not possible to represent or reference POST data in the URL.

Some reading on the definition and difference between post and get: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Answer (score 0):

The GET method pass the parameters INTO the url, for example :

```
http://your/path?yourvariable=value
```

The POST method hide the parameters from the url.

The simplest way to pass parameter with POST method is to make a HTML form. In your Php sript, you can access to this value with the `$_POST` superglobal array.